# Getting the 307 Redirection Response instead of the target-location page content from an enpoint in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, http

So I have a simple endpoint in my Spring Boot App, which just redirects to another website:

@Controller
public class FeedbackController {

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> method() {
    String redirectUrl = "https://www.google.com";
    return Mono
            .just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT).location(URI.create(redirectUrl)).build());
}
```

Making a GET request to this endpoint (e.g. in browser or with postman) gives me the page content of google as a response. However for testing purposes I want to make sure that the response is a TEMPORARY_REDIRECT with [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) as the Location Header.
How can I make a request to this endpoint so that the response is the 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT instead of the 200 with page content from the target website?

Answer (score 0):

### First

to test if its working, you could use simple tools like curl :

> We add the -L flag to tell curl that we want to know if we are getting redirected

```
curl -L http://www.....
```

### Go further

Then, you could simply use tools like MockMvc to automate this test
See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148589/12176221)